# Android ExpandableListView Show only first group name . how to solve this to display full list of group view?

Tags: android

I have problem that in Android ExpandableListView i want to show full list of Group items but there is show only first item . How can i solve it ?
Here i use a productType list in this list a category list in every element.

```
public List<String> header_titles = new ArrayList<>();
public Map<String, List<String>> child_titles = new HashMap<>();
public LayoutInflater minflater;
public Activity activity;

public ShopListAdapter(List<ProductType> productTypes, Context context) {
    for (int i = 0; i < productTypes.size(); i++) {
        if (productTypes.get(i).getCategories().size() != 0) {
            this.header_titles.add(productTypes.get(i).getType());
            List<String> child = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < productTypes.get(i).getCategories().size(); j++) {
                child.add(productTypes.get(i).getCategories().get(j).getCategory());
            }
            child_titles.put(productTypes.get(i).getType(), child);
        }

    }
}

public void setInflater(LayoutInflater mInflater, Activity act) {
    this.minflater = mInflater;
    activity = act;
}


@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    int size = header_titles.size();
    return size;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return header_titles.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return child_titles.get(header_titles.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String title = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }
    TextView group_row = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.group_row);
    group_row.setText(title);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String title = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = minflater.inflate(R.layout.child_row, null);
    }
    TextView tvTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvChildRow);
    tvTitle.setText(title);

    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: please verify how many times this comand `this.header_titles.add(productTypes.get(i).getType());` is executed

Comment: It is executed for 14 times